# Generating and using entity keys within an ndb.Transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions

I'm trying to understand [this code snippet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-search-python-java/blob/master/product_search_python/handlers.py#L197-L212) taken from a sample app showing how to use the App Engine Search API:

```py
rid = models.Review.allocate_ids(size=1)[0]
key = ndb.Key(models.Review._get_kind(), rid)

def _tx():
  review = models.Review(
      key=key,
      product_key=prod.key,
      username=username, rating=rating,
      comment=comment)
  review.put()
  # in a transactional task, update the parent product's average
  # rating to include this review's rating, and flag the review as
  # processed.
  defer(utils.updateAverageRating, key, _transactional=True)
  return review
return ndb.transaction(_tx)
```

So basically it creates a Review entity for a Product and adds a deferred task to update the average rating of that product. I have two questions:

1. Why does this need to be wrapped in a transaction in the first place? What could go wrong if it wasn't placed in a transaction?
2. Why does the Review entity key need to be generated outside the transaction? I wasn't even aware of the `allocate_ids()` method before this example. Wouldn't this simpler alternative work as well?

```py
def _tx():
  review = models.Review(
      product_key=prod.key,
      username=username, rating=rating,
      comment=comment)
  review.put()
  # in a transactional task, update the parent product's average
  # rating to include this review's rating, and flag the review as
  # processed.
  defer(utils.updateAverageRating, review.key, _transactional=True)
  return review
return ndb.transaction(_tx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it either. As far as I can tell there's absolutely no reason to manually allocate the key outside of the transaction. `model.put()` returns the entity's key and you can grab it from the instance as well (as you do in your example). If the `put()` had been asynchronous, I could've seen the logic (I wouldn't have done it that way myself though), but it's not.

There doesn't seem to be any good reason for the transaction either. If you're only updating a single entity with data that does not depend on data that's already persisted to the datastore, you don't need a transaction. The only reason I can think of is ensuring that the deferred task is run only if the transaction applies successfully, but since there's no real reason for having the transaction in the first place you can just get rid of it and skip adding the deferred task if the write operation fails.

Comment: The transaction is useful for the opposite reason: it means the put will be applied only if the deferred task is successfully created.